# Is it possible for $x$ to appear in the definition of $\delta$ in an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof of limit?

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Logic tells me it is not (it would be circular, since the allowed interval for $x$ is itself defined by $\delta$), but I don't know where is the error in my workings. I'll explain...

My doubt arised when studying the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition for non-linear polynomial functions, say a quadratic function, when you want to prove that the limit equals the value of the function at any given value of $x$. This could be the case when checking continuity, for example. As I've seen so far, the normal way of solving the proof for quadratic polynomials consists in converting the epsilon inequality like so:

$$|f(x) - L| < \epsilon = -\epsilon < f(x) - L < \epsilon$$

Then equaling the middle part with de lower side of the $\delta$ inequality and finally choosing the minimum of the two possibilities you get, taken into account you have to assure all values of $x$ will have an image inside the $\epsilon$ interval.

But!

As I've recently realised, the polynomial you get after subtracting the limit to the function when both equal each other, as this nullifies to 0, is *always* factorable. Plus, one of the two factors you get already corresponds to the lower side of the delta inequality. Here is the formal proof of this.

Given:

$$\lim_{x \to n} ax^2 + bx + c = an^2 + bn + c$$

The epsilon inequality of the proof would be:

$$|ax^2 + bx + c - (an^2 + bn + c)| < \epsilon$$

And working from that:

$$|ax^2 + bx + c - an^2 - bn - c| < \epsilon$$
$$|ax^2 + bx - an^2 - bn| < \epsilon$$
$$|a(x^2 - n^2) + b(x - n)| < \epsilon$$
$$|a(x + n)(x - n) + b(x - n)| < \epsilon$$
$$|(x - n)(a(x + n) + b)| < \epsilon$$
$$|x - n||a(x + n) + b| < \epsilon$$
$$|x - n| < \frac{\epsilon}{|a(x + n) + b|}$$

And there it is! You'll always have the lower side of the delta inequality on the left. Thus, you could define $\delta$ as:

$$\delta \le \frac{\epsilon}{|a(x + n) + b|}$$

*Et voilà!* Here you have $x$ defining delta.

Now, obviously something weird is going on here... isn't it? I highly suspect my math is flawed at some point, possibly when handling absolute values. Add to that I have no idea how to connect this method with the one that has to choose between two possible values of $\delta$.

Any help with this mess would be much appreciated!

Comment: The difference between uniformly continuity and continuity is that for uniform continuity the value of δ depends only on ε and not on the point $x$ in the domain

Comment: $\delta$ depends on $\epsilon $ and the point of consideration (here $n$). The values of the variable $x$ are then constrained by the value of $\delta$ chosen by inequality $0<|x-n|<\delta$. Further the definition requires you to prove the existence of a $\delta $ with desired properties and one does not need to have an explicit expression for $\delta$.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to check the continuity at some point $x$, the very first thing you do is fix $x$. From that point on, $x$ is a **constant**, like $2$ or $3$. Saying that you're unhappy to see $x$ in $\delta$ *in such a case* is like saying that you're unhappy to see $2$ or $3$.

Now in your situation, you are correct that there is a problem, given that $x$ is a *variable* that tends to $n$, while $n$ is the fixed one, so it makes no sense to have $x$ part of the definition of $\delta$.

However, you can easily get rid of the $x$-depending right-hand side but to do that you need to fix the causality in your succession of lines, i.e. insert $\Rightarrow$, $\Leftarrow$, $\Leftrightarrow$ where relevant. It is very important to do this all the time, otherwise you forget what you want to prove and you end up writing down things that make no sense.

So let's do that, what you need is $|x-n|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(n)|<\varepsilon$. So we need $$|x - n| < \frac{\epsilon}{|a(x + n) + b|}\Longleftarrow |x - n| < \delta$$
And for that it is enough to have $\delta$ **less than** all values assumed by the function $\frac{\epsilon}{|a(x + n) + b|}$ when $x$ covers a close neighbourhood of $n$. You can easily check that no matter what $a$ and $b$ are, there is such a $\delta$.

Comment: The OP is not checking for continuity at $x$, but in $n$ instead. $x$ is not constant.

Comment: @HarisGusic Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: I think I don't quite get it. Could you show a worked example? Say, $\lim_{x\to 2} x^2 + 4$, where we'd have $\frac{\epsilon}{|x + n|}$, without $a$ nor $b$. Am I supposed to try plugging different values and see which ones make the inequalities hold? In this case for instance, given $n = 2$, if I choose $\epsilon = 3$ I'd have to choose $x > 1$ in order to make the $\epsilon$ inequality hold. But then I don't know exactly what I'm supposed to do with $\delta$. I feel I understand it a little more, but I don't get to wrap my head around the whole thing.

Comment: @AlejandroCambra I assume $n>0$ to make it simpler to think about. Then, when $x$ lies in the interval $[\frac n2, n+\frac n2]$, the denominator $|x+n|$ is always less than $|2n|$, which is a **constant**, and hence $\frac{\varepsilon}{|x+n|}$ is always more than $\frac{\varepsilon}{|2n|}$, so $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{|2n|}$ works.

Comment: Oh, OK, I think I'm getting it. But shouldn't the constant be $|3n|$? Because $x$ could be $n + \frac{n}{2}$, thus $|x + n| = |\frac{5n}{2}| > |2n|$. And couldn't be set the constant without the absolute value operator, since $n$ is defined as positive? Now. If I understand correctly, the process consists in first defining an interval for $x$ and then setting a constant higher than the denominator under $\epsilon$, isn't it? Still, I have some doubts surrounding $x$. What "is" it? What would be its graphic representation? Does it need to be defined as an interval, and centered around $n$?

Comment: @AlejandroCambra right, my bad, replace every instance of $2n$ by $3n$ in my comment.

Comment: $x$ is just a variable that can take arbitrary values, but if you look at the definition of continuity, only values arbitrarily close to $n$ are significant.

Comment: OK, I've been trying to recap these days, and I have a doubt related to your first question: why can't we define $\delta$ as $\frac{\epsilon}{|a(x + n) + b|}$, instead of as lower than that? Wasn't delta defined as lower or EQUAL TO that expression? Apart from that, I've found another possible caveat. Take $\lim_{x \to 2} x^2 + 4$ again, and choose $\epsilon = 3$ and $x = n + \frac{n}{2} = 3$. Now, $|x - n| < \frac{\epsilon}{|3n|}$ equals $1 < \frac{1}{2}$, which obviously does not hold.

Comment: @AlejandroCambra $\delta$ is defined as lower than or equal to **any possible value taken** by that expression, as $x$ varies. Really, your first hunch was dead right, it really makes no sense to have $x$ in the definition of $\delta$. In fact, $x$ is a **bound variable** that makes sense only within the limit $\lim_{x\to \ldots}$.

Comment: @AlejandroCambra That's not a caveat. All we're saying is that **IF** $|x-n|<\delta$ **THEN** $|f(x)-f(n)|<\varepsilon$. But $|x-n|\geq \delta$ may very well happen, that's fine.

Comment: Then why did you say that "it is enough to have $\delta$ *less than* all values assumed by the function"? And how is $|x - n| \geq \delta$ allowed by the proof?

Comment: @AlejandroCambra If you don't understand that point the best is to actually rewrite your proof, as I suggested, by first stating what you want, and then including the relevant $\implies$ signs.